# why do i not have the same data when pull github

Tags: reactjs, json, git, github, git-pull

i am triying to pull a branch in my local but i didn't have the same data like in github repository, in the terminal, says: `Already up to date`.

For examples in my github repository, i have a file named `data.json`, the content of this this is not the same as the `data.json` i have in my local repository.

Here is the github link : https://github.com/Meriemu/TestCaseLvmh/blob/feature/slider/public/data.json

And here is a screnshot of my local data :
[image]

Comment: Why negative rate !!

Comment: I think, you are looking in different branches. Make sure that you compare the same branch remote and local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it,
actually i was in a gitlab repository and not github, that's why. i had to remove the origin and re-add it and pull the branch. My answer could help others, maybe...

Answer (score 0):

You see to have the [`public/data.json` from commit `ded8223`](https://github.com/Meriemu/TestCaseLvmh/blob/ded82237fa3eeab390f316bfad47eddee5c7afda/public/data.json)

Check what `git status` tells you, as well as `git branch -avv`, in order to double-check where you are in this repository history.

Comment: that's a commit of 21 days ago, here is the last one : (https://github.com/Meriemu/TestCaseLvmh/commit/02e9aaffc02c7263aa379a9cd23844766dcea44e)

Comment: with the `git status` i have this :  `On branch feature/slider
nothing to commit, working tree clean`